# How to add multiple views to a split-view controller?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4

I am developing an app for the iPad, using split-view and storyboards. I did this once before quite a while ago but didn't write down how to do it. I've googled and SO'd all morning and found nothing specifically targeting my question.

I know there is a way to add multiple detail views by dragging objects to the storyboard canvas, and somehow (that's the question) setting the new object as either master or detail...

Anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up... decided to go to with a tab bar controller; much simpler.  And the fact that it got voted down indicates to me nobody knows the answer.

Thanks anyway to all who looked at it.